# How should i perform update operation in one to many annotation based mapping on existing parent?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have one(Vendor) and many(customers). I am updating parent object having `vid=101` in the database with three new customer object. The problem is that in the database this `vid=101` associate with newly created child objects, but for old two customer objects it goes null. This problem is coming only in annotation-based code. With `xml` based mapping its working.

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
        Vendor v = (Vendor)session.get(Vendor.class, 100);


    Customer c1 = new Customer();
    c1.setCustomerId(502);
    c1.setCustomerName("Rajveer");

    Customer c2 = new Customer();
    c2.setCustomerId(503);
    c2.setCustomerName("Abhishek");

    Set s = new HashSet();
    s.add(c1);
    s.add(c2);
    s=v.getChildren();
    v.setChildren(s);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    s=v.getChildren();
    session.saveOrUpdate(v);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Perform all operations within one transaction.

**2)** Set the parent for each child.

**3)** Add to the fetched child list. You are overriding the existing one

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Vendor v = (Vendor)session.get(Vendor.class, 100);

Customer c1 = new Customer();
c1.setCustomerId(502);
c1.setCustomerName("Rajveer");
c1.setParent(v);

Customer c2 = new Customer();
c2.setCustomerId(503);
c2.setCustomerName("Abhishek");
c2.setParent(v);

Set s = new HashSet();
s.add(c1);
s.add(c2);

v.addChildren(s); // Add, not Set, unless you want to delete existing ones

session.saveOrUpdate(v);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: But this approach is used in many to one mapping, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: So its auni-directional mapping? Can you add code of the entities?

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name = "Vendor")
 @Column(name = "vname", length=30)
 private String vendorName;
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=Customer.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "venid", referencedColumnName="vid")

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")@Id @Column(name = "custid")
 private int customerId; @Column(name = "custName", length=30)
 private String customerName;

Comment: is there any change in procedure for update operation while shifting from xml to annotation ?

Comment: You are right I am creating HashSet object, which is cause for null value.